# Compose method called once

Tags: android, kotlin, click

I try to call very simple compose method from fragment button but when i try to click on the button the compose method just called once and the log shown once !

```
@Composable
fun showOverlay(){
    Log.e("showverlayTag", "showVodafoneOverlay: ", )
}
```

And the click is here inside the onCreate fragment :

```
binding.sCashMoneyTransferGiftsSwitch.setOnClickListener {
        binding.composeView.setContent {
            showOverlay()
        }

    }
```

i want whatever i click on the button the log is called and shown on the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Compose view called once when you click the button because nothing happened after click the button that trigger the recomposition and re call the method .. to do that without handle state or any thing just call `compose.setContent={}`  .. this code act as reset the compose and then every click will treat compose as first time clicking.

Answer (score 1):

`setContent` is telling the ComposeView what view hierarchy to show. Your button click listener is setting the same content over and over, so there's nothing triggering Compose to recompose its views because their State hasn't changed. Code like your `println` that appears inside a Composable will only be called when the view hierarchy recomposes in response to a State change. And even then, it might be skipped if Compose doesn't detect that particular branch of the UI being modified by the change in State.

This behavior is what we want. Compose is supposed to smartly not rerun code that's not necessary to update the UI because that slows down the app and makes it janky. It's also the reason you want to avoid calling side-effect code like this in Composables. Logging is acceptable on a temporary basis to debug something, but it's similar to side-effect code.

If you want code to be called every time a button is pressed, you should put that code directly in the click listener, not inside a Composable's code.